# Which attributes or methods are available by heritage to subclasses?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am currently learning Python, moved from the basics to Object Oriented Programming implementation. For instance, in the code snippet below (I've written it from the top of my head, sorry if it looks, amateur)

```
class A_subclass(The_superclass):
    pass
```

I wanted to clearly understand the attributes/methods that are available by heritage to subclasses. If we use the code example above. *A_subclass* has inherited all the attributes & methods from *The_superclass*. Are there any exemptions? or the sub-class *A_subclass*  has everything that the parent class *The_superclass* has?

Comment: anything that doesnt start with `__` should inherit normally ... to access items defined with `__` you will need to look into name_mangling.  if it both starts and ends with `__` then it is a special variable (ie `__str__`) and should also inherit normally

Comment: Have you seen any OOP code in python? Can you provide any code which you have a problem understanding?

Comment: @quamrana. Yes I have. Okay, right from the top of my head :                                
class Base():
    """ My base class """

    __nb_instances = 0

    def __init__(self):
        Base.__nb_instances += 1
        self.id = Base.__nb_instances

b = Base()
print(b.id)

Comment: @JoranBeasley from your explanation. I understand that all attributes can be inherited. Apart from the private. Which can only be accessed using the name mangling process - dir() ? If yes, that means without using the name mangling process. Private attributes are never available to subclasses?

Comment: Please update your question with this code so it is properly formatted.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @JoranBeasley those attributes are *inherited* in precisely the same way, but the *compiler* mangles the names you write in source code inside a class definition taht start like that

Comment: @KevinNjuguna no, **all attributes** (methods are just attributes) are inherited. Python *does not have private attributes*, i.e. python does not have access modifiers. Name mangling is *merely* meant to prevent *accidental* name-collisions in subclasses. But you *know* that if `SomeClass.__some_name = 0` is defined in `SomeClass`, then it is available using `SomeChildCLass._SomeClass__some_name` if you want it it, just as it is on the original class

Comment: @quamrana & abdo Salm. I've edited the question and added a code with an empty class that inherits from its parent class.

Comment: In some other languages, inheritance means actively pulling attributes from a parent into the definition of the child. In Python, it just means failed attribute lookups on an instance can be deleted to the parent.

Comment: Yes, now seeing your code, I would say that it is almost redundant and equivalent to: `A_subclass = The_superclass` ie just giving the base class an additional name.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Ouh!! interesting. This makes me understand it better now. From Joran's explanation. It seems like there are attributes/methods that are inherited or accessed differently from the rest. So if an existing attribute/method name exists from any classes inherited, to prevent accidental name collisions. Name-mangling way of naming is used. If so, that means all attributes/methods are available to be inherited?

Comment: @quamrana Thanks for driving the point home. I think I've got it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subclass “inherits” all the attributes (methods, etc) of the parent class. This means that a subclass will have everything that its “parents” have.
You can then change (“override”) some or all of the attributes to change the behavior. You can also add new attributes to extend the behavior.

Thus. All attributes & methods are available by heritage to subclasses.